# How to check if a custom post is in a specific taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I want to check if there is at least one female in the custom post and if there is one I want to set the condition to true: `$has_one_female = true;`

But it never enters in this if:

```
    foreach($team_members as $team_member) {

    if(has_category( 'female', $team_member)) {

        $has_one_female = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

See complete code below:

```
$args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'team', 
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category-team',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('team', 'female') 
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$team_members = array();
$has_one_female = false;

if($query->have_posts()) {
    $team_members = $query->posts;
    print_r($query);
    $has_one_female = false;
    foreach($team_members as $team_member) {
    
        if(has_category( 'female', $team_member)) {
          
            $has_one_female = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about the actual `category` taxnonomy WP provides by default, or a custom taxnomy you added yourself? For the latter, you’d need to use `has_term`.

Comment: It's a custom taxonomy, I tried if(has_term('female', $team_member)) {.... }, but still it doesn't get inside the if statement.

Comment: `has_term` takes up to _three_ parameters, and the second one is the name of the custom taxonomy. Please go read up on stuff like this, if you are not sure, rather than just _guess_. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

Answer (score 1):

Would **in_category()** suffice?

So you would then do something like:

```
if (in_category('female')) {
}
```

you could also check an array like:

```
if (in_category( ['female', 'other'] )) {}
```

If you would need to check based on a custom taxonomy I think you would be able to use this as well:

```
if (has_term('female', 'gender_taxonomy_name')) {}
```

**There's a difference in checking categories or taxonomies:**

Check post for category — use in_category()
Check post for tax term — use has_term()